# Expand a UICollectionView in the middle of rows

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` like following:

[image]

Is it possible to add scrollable content in the middle of rows on click of a cell like following:
[image]

If yes, then how?

Comment: Someone down voted my question for a spelling mistake!!!
Seriously? And I thought that is what the edits are for. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this sample to your own need.

[Expandable UICollectionView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rbcollectionviewinfofolderlayout)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like what I need. Will get back to you on how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create 2 custom `UICollectionView` layouts. One without spacing and another one with it. Then animate change of the layout using method:

```
setCollectionViewLayout:animated:completion:
```

Comment: This is not a workaround but a decent way of doing it. Modifying a layout and animating the change. Adding extra, unused cells would be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to assume you're using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for this purpose.

What you can simply do is add a new `Cell` at the desired indexPath and in the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` datasource method, return the desired size (full width, required height). The flow layout will handle the rest for you.

Inside that cell, you can use a UIScrollView to get the Scrollable Content.

**Update**

Your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` will look something like this

```
if(indexPath.item == myItemIndex && indexPath.section == myItemSection)
{
    return CGSizeMake(768,200);
}
else
{
    return CGSizeMake(128,128);
}
```

The values above are just examples. Modify them to suit your needs.

Comment: Hmm. I will try. But won't the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` change the size of all the cells?

Comment: You can check the indexPath and send the larger size only for your cell. For all other cells return the normal size.